# How to use environments like array inline

Tags: alignment

There are some environments such as align, array or matrix that is usually in display mode.

However there's another multi-line environment which can be used inline called cases. So I'm thinking whether there's a way to change them from display to inline.

Comment: For `align`, you can use `$\begin{aligned} … end{aligned}$`. For `matrix`, you have the `smallmatrix`  environment.

Comment: Please provide a code example. Thanks